Testing PI controller for its long term error and drift property
I have built  PI controller shown in the LTSPICE photo.
I know that one  of it properties is to handle long term error to trend to zero and handle drift.
Is there a way I can simulate this effect how it handles a drift or a long tern error to zero?



You can create a test scenario where the input signal (setpoint) and the feedback signal (measured value) are mismatched over time. This mismatch creates an error, and the integrator in the PI controller works to reduce this error to zero.

Could you please demonstrate it in LTSPICE or some equivalent ? I am having problem imagine your words.

You need to simulate the system being controlled by the controller (aka the 'plant').
The simplest system would be something like a voltage divider, which has no dynamics. There will be an error initially if the proportional gain is not ideal and that error should disappear over time.
You can add dynamics with capacitors and such like and inject disturbances with time-dependent voltage sources etc.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
In this case your setpoint is 0 so you have to set some non-zero initial condition to see the controller work.

Could you please demonstrate it in LTSPICE or some equivalent ? I am having problem imagine your words.

See edit. You should simulate it and play with the results to fully understand it. With the lower circuit you may be able to demonstrate control loop instability if it is poorly tuned.

The controller output is an input to the plant. The plant output (PV) is an input to the controller. You'll typically have a second input to the controller (SV) - the setpoint.

Inject a current into the R1/R2 junction in my top circuit (after some delay time) to simulate a disturbance. There should be an initial offset and the plant output (PV) should return to zero.

Hello, I see the drift as a constant increase in the error signal ,so its like a ramp. I made two photos ,of the circuit and simulation input output. I see that the output is an input opposite,How can I make the feedback element in LTSPICE so I'll get the ramp at the output will be combined with the input getting back the desired 0V. Thanks
https://ibb.co/kGGXfgb
https://ibb.co/zQRxgG4

Here's a plant that exhibits a "dead zone" 4V wide, and undershoots by about that same amount:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Between 3ms and 5ms there's very little output response to input changes under 4V. This could represent static friction of a stalled motor, for example, something that the integrator in a PID controller should be able to overcome.

Hello, I see the drift as a constant increase in the error signal ,so its like a ramp. I made two photos ,of the circuit and simulation input output. I see that the output is an input opposite,How can I make the feedback element in LTSPICE so I'll get the ramp at the output will be combined with the input getting back the desired 0V. Thanks
https://ibb.co/kGGXfgb
https://ibb.co/zQRxgG4
